# clang-format style file path format is not working

Tags: bash, msys2, clang-format

I'm using `clang-format` 15. According tot he [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormat.html) it is possible to specify custom style file with the `--style` option using `--style='file:<format_file_path>`.

However, I'm having problem with actual path specification that doesn't produce the `Invalid value for -style` error. If the format file is local like this, everything is fine:

```
clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style='file:cmt.txt' -Werror ./template.h
```

But if it is located somewhere else, nothing works. I've tried these possibilities:

```
clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style='file:/cmt.txt' -Werror ./template.h
clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style="file:/cmt.txt" -Werror ./template.h
clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style=file://cmt.txt -Werror ./template.h
clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style=file:\/cmt.txt -Werror ./template.h
```

Is there some special character combination that `clang-format` will accept?
I'm using bash 5.2.15 in msys2.

Comment: Do you have that file at the FS root?

Comment: can you tell us more about the project structure please ? when i try clang-format --dry-run --fcolor-diagnostics --verbose --style='file:cmt.txt' -Werror src/specific/toto/source/toto.cpp and when the cmt.txt file is located in the execution command folder it work's for me

Comment: Yes, @TomPenard, as I've mentioned, putting the configuration file located locally as you did in your command works. But it my project it is located in a different submodule. Thus if I apply some path - `clang-format` doesn't like it.

Comment: This is likely to be an MSYS2 path conversion issue.  Please run `which clang-format` so we can see if it's a MinGW (native Windows) program or not.  Then tell us the full Windows-style path to cmt.txt (e.g. `C:\cmt.txt`).

Comment: ```$ which clang-format```

```/mingw64/opt/llvm-15/bin/clang-format```